# Let $E = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1x_2 > 1 \text{ and } x_1 > 0\}$. Let $a\in E$. Prove that there exists $r>0$ such that $C_r(a)\subseteq E$

Tags: real-analysis

$C_r(a) = \{x\in  \mathbb{R}^n : |x_i - a_i| < r \text{ for }i = 1,...,n\}$ (aka an Open cube....|*| is absolute value)

My beginnings of an atempt proof (by contradiction):

Suppose that for all r > 0 we have $C_r(a)\not \subseteq E$ for $a \in E$. Let $x\in C_r(a)$. Then $x\not \in E$. Then we have $$|x_i - a_i| < r \text{ and } x_1x_2 \leq 1 \text{ or } x_1 \leq 0.$$ Since $a \in E $, we know $a_1a_2$ > 1 and $a_1 > 0$. Then......I don't really know where to go from here! Should I even be trying to do a contradiction here?

Could the r I'm looking for be r = 2a?

Comment: Since $\mathbb (0, \infty)$ is Hausdorff, the graph of $f(x) = 1/x$ is closed by [this theorem](http://planetmath.org/graphtheoremsfortopologicalspaces). Do you know enough topology to understand the linked proof?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=(x_1,x_2)\in E$. From the definition of $E$, $x_1>0$ and $x_2>\frac{1}{x_1}$. Without lose of generality suppose that $x_2>x_1$. Take the radius $r>0$ such that $r=\frac{x_2+(x_2-1/x_1)}{2}$(if necessary take $r$ less that the distance between $(x_1,x_2)$ and the origin and axis). So any point in the open ball $C_r(x_1,x_2)$ satisfy the requerid. This is because by our choose of $r$, any point $(x,y)$ in this ball, satisfy the inequalities $x_1-r<x<x_1+r$ and $x_2-r<y<x_2+r$. Thus we only need to prove that $(2x_1-x_2+1/x_1)(2x_2-x_1+1/x_2)>4$ but this is easy from the inequality $a/b+b/a>2$ if $ab>0$ and $a\neq b$.

Comment: what is "radio r"?